# Do I want to be able to use host-only networking in my virtual machines?

Tags: installation, vmware-server

While installing vmware server I'm asked

> Do you want to be able to use host-only networking in your virtual machines? [yes]

what do they mean by this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Host-only networking creates a network that is completely contained within the host computer.](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_net_configurations_hostonly.html)

Sorry SO. Forgot to Google first.

Answer (score 0):

I actually find the NAT networking so much more useful in practice.  If you have a VM that you need to update or grab the occasional package from the net.  This is so handy I never create host only VMs anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Host-only networking is a way to restrict a VM's networking capability to talk to the outside world. It means the VM can only communicate with the host.

I've rarely found a need for it, since I almost always want the guest to be able to access the entire internet, not just the host machine.

However, the question being asked is: do you want to **allow** host-only networking? You still won't be forced to use it for all your VMs, so I would say yes. You will still be able to configure your VMs for full access.

Comment: Yeah, that kinda threw me off. I wanted the least restricted set up possible. I ultimately chose [no] and I think I got what I needed.

Comment: True, and when you do need fully-restricted networking, you can use LAN segments with teams. (AFAIK, host-only networking is like a big LAN segment made up of all running VMs on the same host. Teams allows you to specify which VMs are allowed in.)